# $(document).on("click"... how to collapse a list when clicking anywhere else on the document

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a collapsible/expandable menu for my website. I had a version where hovering over a category would cause the subcategory to expand, but what I really want is to click on a category and have the subcategories expand and remain expanded until I click anywhere else on the page. I think I'm close--I've looked at a lot of examples and am just struggling to piece them all together.

The current situation is that I can get the lists to expand and collapse when clicking on the lists themselves, but I can't get anything to happen when clicking elsewhere on the document. I realize that I'll also have to do something with stopPropagation(), but first things first...

Javascript:

```
function show_sub(cat){
  cat.querySelector("ul").style.display = (cat.querySelector("ul").style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
};

$('body').on("click", function () {
    $("#nav ul").style.display="none";
});
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    width: 120px;
    border: black 1px solid;
}
#nav li > ul {
    display:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="cat1" onclick="show_sub(this)">Vegetables
        <ul>
            <li>Beans</li>
            <li>Carrots</li>
            <li>Greens</li>
            <li>Onions</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li id="cat2" onclick="show_sub(this)">Fruit
            <ul>
                <li>Apple</li>
                <li>Banana</li>
                <li>Cantaloupe</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

[link to jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6ozq1La/5/)

Thanks in advance for your patience. I don't have much experience with Javascript and I've found Stack Overflow enormously helpful as I figure out how to make changes to existing websites. However, I'm still floundering around when it comes to creating anything from scratch.

EDIT: Used solution from @JustinMorgan and added one line so that only one submenu is visible at a time: http://jsfiddle.net/nbavc5g7/2/

Comment: Tip: Why are you mixing up Vanilla Javascript with jQuery whereas you could use one or the other?

Comment: @MelanciaUK, what's wrong with mixing Vanilla and jQuery?

Comment: Nothing wrong, that's why it was just a tip. Most of the code could be done by using one or the other.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/x6ozq1La/8/

Comment: @MelanciaUK, you should add it as an answer. :)

Comment: It was a first attempt, there are better answers below.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I was mixing Vanilla and jQuery because I didn't know any better, basically... I've been grabbing snippets of code from different examples that I've found, and since my project uses jQuery anyway, I didn't pay much attention to which was which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were right, you do need `stopPropagation`. The same click event that expands the sub-list is propagating up the chain, where the click handler on `body` immediately hides it again.

You can also simplify your code in a few places. Try this:

```
$('#nav > li').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('ul', this).show(); 
});

$('body').on("click", function () {
    $("#nav ul").hide();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d60Lcq9j/1/

EDIT: Here's a slightly more complex version that lets you close the submenu with a second click to its header. This version doesn't stop event propagation:

```
$('#nav li').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        $(this).children('ul').toggle(); 
    }
});

$('body').on("click", function (e) {
    var item = $(e.target).closest('#nav > li');
    $('#nav > li')
        .not(item)
        .find('ul')
        .hide();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Luk35kb6/

Comment: @MelanciaUK - Having thought about it, if this is a clickable submenu, it won't do to have it close again when you click inside it. If you want it to close when you click the parent item, then the code is more complicated than just replacing `show` with `toggle`. I'll edit.

Comment: I like your edit, @MelanciaUK--I wish you would submit it so that I could accept it as a solution.

Comment: @floctime - `toggle` alone won't do what you want. Try my edit.

Comment: @JustinMorgan stopping event propagation is not a good idea. http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Comment: @justinmorgan, it will indeed be a clickable submenu, so once you click on an item in the submenu, you'll be going to a different page anyway (so the submenu does not need to collapse). However, I would like to only have one submenu open at a time--so if you click on a new category, the old submenu will close. I think this is something that I can fiddle around with though--you've gotten me much much closer to where I want to be. Thank you!

Comment: @ArnelleBalane - Stopping event propagation is *sometimes* not a good idea, depending on your situation. Like all techniques, it has risks and benefits, but it's not established as a bad practice. Your revenge-downvoting is extremely transparent.

Comment: I added a line so that only one submenu is visible at a time: http://jsfiddle.net/nbavc5g7/2/. Thanks, everyone, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your click event handler for the `body` element, check whether the click originated from the navigation `li`s or from anywhere else on the page, and toggle your lists accordingly.

So your code will now look like:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li id="cat1">Vegetables
      <ul>
        <li>Beans</li>
        <li>Carrots</li>
        <li>Greens</li>
        <li>Onions</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="cat2">Fruit
      <ul>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Banana</li>
        <li>Cantaloupe</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#nav li').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});

$('body').on("click", function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('#nav li').length) {
    $(e.target).closest('#nav li ul').toggle();
  } else {
    $('#nav li ul').hide();
  }
});
```

**CSS** (as @wonderwhy pointed out in the comments)

```
#nav > li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav li > ul {
  display: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Check out this fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arnellebalane/x6ozq1La/9/

Just a note: Please move away from using `onclick` and similar attributes in your HTML document. Since you're using jQuery, you can attach the event handlers unobstrusively in your javascript scripts using the `on()` method.

Comment: And also aesthetically a hand when mouse over to add the css would be better. Otherwise user may not realize you can get the rest of the content with clicking over the <li> tag.

Comment: The handler-binding style wasn't the problem. Whether to use `onclick` or not is purely a matter of preference.

Comment: @JustinMorgan yes you are right, but I believe that HTML must be used for structuring the document, not to decide how it should behave, and that Javascript should be kept out of the HTML as much as possible (idk if I explained it right, but just think of why we place stylesheets into a separate CSS file instead of using the `style` attribute, the reason is somewhat similar).

Comment: I prefer the unobtrusive style as well, but it's not the cause of the problem here. The way you worded your answer made it sound like it was. Coding-style is really a side note here.

Comment: @JustinMorgan I meant it to be a suggestion, sorry for the wrong/unclear wording. And thanks for the word ("unobstrusive") btw..

Comment: You're welcome, and I'll be happy to remove the downvote if you word it to make that more clear.